# Given $a+b=x$ ,and $a-b=y$.Prove that $x^{2}+y^{2}=2(a^{2}+b^{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Given $a+b=x$ ,and $a-b=y$.Prove that $x^2+y^2=2(a^2+b^2)$**

From where should I start?because I have not got any idea!

Comment: What exactly are you in trouble with? Do you know how to square sums?

Comment: People don't just give you answers here.

Comment: Is this even elementary number theory or discrete mathematics or algebraic number theory? And what seems to be the problem?

Comment: You just need to square and add. Please elaborate what's your problem and what you have tried.

Comment: So how  you suggest  I should edit the question Eleven Eleven?

Comment: Sorry guys I am new here I will edit the question thanks

Comment: Honestly, just show what you did, what you think you should do to solve and why your getting stuck.

Comment: Um.... if x = a+b then $x^2 = (a+b)^2$.  Did that really not occur to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very rude way to ask but still i am answering

Its very simple

$X=A+B$

1.$X^2=A^2+B^2+2AB$

$Y=A-B$

2.$Y^2=A^2+B^2+C^2$

SIMPLY ADD 1 AND 2 YOU WILL GET IT

Comment: Sorry for my rude question I just do not know the way  to ask here sorry again

Comment: Its ok you can accept and upvote me if u like the solution

Comment: What was wrong in this to get a downvote @ developer

Comment: @user36312 Welcome to Maths SE!!Don't worry....Questions that show what the author has tried are better accepted here...from next time try posting your thoughts,experience level etc. to make your question more informative and better accepted....Thanks!!

Comment: @user36312 See this on how to ask a good question-http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Start at the beginning.

$x= a+ b$ and $y = a-b$ so $x^2 + y^2 = (a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2= ....$

"**I just need the answer**"

That's not how we roll here.

Comment: Okay okay calm down I am new here and just do not know the way to question here I guess that is why ny account was not able to post question for a 100 times! LOL tganks anyway

Comment: Okay okay calm down I am new here and just do not know the way to question here I guess that is why ny account was not able to post question for a 100 times! LOL thanks anyway

Comment: Who is not "calm" here, exactly?

Comment: To be fair, did.  My first edit of the post was a lot more emphatic...."I just need the answer" *really* sets me off and I *really* made a big issue that one should !!!!!!NEVER!!!! !!!!EVER!!!! say that here.  .. A bit emphatic ....

Comment: Guys sorry I will learn the way questions are being asked here I promise sorry again fleablood

Answer (score 0):

When $x=\text{a}+\text{b}$ and $y=\text{a}-\text{b}$, find $x^2+y^2$:

$$x^2+y^2=\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)^2+\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)^2$$

Now:

1. $$\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)^2=\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)=\text{a}\text{a}+\text{a}\text{b}+\text{a}\text{b}+\text{b}\text{b}=\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2+2\text{a}\text{b}$$
2. $$\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)^2=\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)=\text{a}\text{a}-\text{a}\text{b}-\text{a}\text{b}-\text{b}\cdot\left(-\text{b}\right)=\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2-2\text{a}\text{b}$$

So:

$$x^2+y^2=\left(\text{a}+\text{b}\right)^2+\left(\text{a}-\text{b}\right)^2=\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2+2\text{a}\text{b}+\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2-2\text{a}\text{b}=$$
$$\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2+\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2=2\left(\text{a}^2+\text{b}^2\right)$$